# Color mixing or blend

Tags: graphics, image-processing, color

Color mixing seems not only one type.

[Here is RGB_color_model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model)

I wrote this one:

```
coord = 1/2*{{1, -Sqrt[3]/3}, {0, 2 Sqrt[3]/3}, {-1, -Sqrt[3]/3}};
color = {Red, Green, Blue};
MapThread[
  Graphics[{##}, PlotRange -> 2, Background -> Black] &, {color, 
   Disk /@ coord}];
Plus @@ (ImageData /@ %) // Image
Clear[coord, color]
```

[image]

Another type of mixing is :

```
{#, Graphics[{#, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 50]} & /@ 
 DeleteDuplicates[Blend /@ Permutations[{Red, Blue, Green}, {2}]]
```

[image]

So How can I get the following like this ?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update 2:**

Use `ImageApply` to replace the channel values of each pixel with the values that correspond to blended values:

```
img=Image[Plus @@ (ImageData /@ MapThread[Graphics[{##}, PlotRange -> 2, 
  Background -> Black] &,  {color,  Disk /@ coord}])];
ImageApply[If[Tr[#] == 0, #, #/Tr[#]] &, img]
```

or, better yet, (courtesy of J.M.)

```
ImageApply[Normalize[#, Tr] &, img]
```

[image]

---

**Update 1:**

Post-process the original image to replace intersection colors with the blended versions:

```
ImageData[img] /.  {{1., 1., 1.} -> {1./3, 1./3, 1./3},
    {1., 1., 0.} -> {1./2, 1./2, 0.},
    {0., 1., 1.} -> {0., 1./2, 1./2},
    {1., 0., 1.} -> {1./2, 0., 1./2}} // Image
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

You can use `RegionPlot` to get a picture with circle intersections colored using `Blend`:

```
circles = (0 <= (x - #[[1]])^2 + (y - #[[2]])^2 <= 1) & /@ coord;
subregions =  Most@(And @@ # & /@ (Thread[{#, circles}] & /@ 
   Tuples[{Identity, Not}, Length@circles] /. {x_, y_} :> x[y]));
subregioncolors = Thread[{#, color}] & /@
     Tuples[{Identity, # /. # -> Sequence[] &}, Length@color] /.
        {x_, y_} :> x[y] /. {} -> Sequence[];
subregioncolors = Map[Blend@Flatten@{#1, #1} & , subregioncolors];
RegionPlot[subregions, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
    PlotStyle -> subregioncolors, BoundaryStyle -> White,
    PlotPoints -> 150, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

Comment: Thans,but it's a bit slower.

Comment: Excellent! Is "ImageApply[If[Tr[#] == 0, #, #/Tr[#]] &, img]" equivalent to 
"Map[If[Tr[#] == 0, #, #/Tr[#]] &, img // ImageData, {2}] // Image" ?

Comment: @chyanog, I think it is. BTW, similarly, `Plus @@ (ImageData /@ %) // Image` does the same thing to image data as `Fold[ImageAdd,First@%,Rest@%]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Now I see.

Comment: Slightly more compact: `ImageApply[Normalize[#, Tr] &, img]`

Comment: @J.M. thank you! much more elegant (as always).

Answer (score 12):

Although kguler correctly yields the picture that you set as a goal here I wonder whether this really is what is behind the question.

You mention *another type of mixing* and since you start with an example of *additive* mixing of the RGB primaries I feel you may have the intention to deal with *subtractive* mixing of colors.

The primary colors of *subtractive* mixing, the type of mixing that deals with paints and printed colors, are Yellow, Cyan, and Magenta:

```
{#, Graphics[{#, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 50]} & /@ {Yellow, Magenta, Cyan}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The colors you provided are just murkier versions of them (you used 1/2's instead of 1's).

You can see Cyan, Magenta, and Yellow as "negative" Red, Green and Blue respectively. Using a slightly changed version of your code:

```
coord = 1/2*{{1, -Sqrt[3]/3}, {0, 2 Sqrt[3]/3}, {-1, -Sqrt[3]/3}};
color = {Red, Green, Blue};
circles = MapThread[Image[Graphics[{##}, PlotRange -> 2, Background -> Black], 
    ImageSize -> 300] &, {color, Disk /@ coord}]

ImageSubtract[Image[ConstantArray[{1, 1, 1}, {300, 300}], "Real"], #] & /@ circles // Row
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using that, you can now easily crate the three overlapping circles of subtractive color mixing.

```
Fold[ImageSubtract,Image[ConstantArray[{1, 1, 1}, {300, 300}], "Real"], circles]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `ColorNegate[img]` gives the same result? (where `img` is the first image in OP's question)

Comment: @kguler Yes, but I found it more instructive to build it up as three separate subtractions. It gets you closer to the process that is subtractive mixing.