# graphics - Overlaping Image in red and green scale, mixing pure colors

Tags: graphics, image-processing, color, image, overlay

How can I overlap/merge two density plot (in attach) using Mathematica. One image is in red scale and the other is in green scale.

[image]

In theses two images the lowest value is white (background) and the highest values are represented by pure red [ RGB (255,0,0) ] and green [ RGB (0,255,0) ] scale.

How do I to overlap these two images such that intersections are a combination of red and green to give a yellow intensity [ RGB (255,255,0) ]  dependent on the "red" and "green" values. **In summary I need that resultant image had red, green and yellow colors**.

I already tried these examples:

- [Overlapping Red and Green ArrayPlots to show yellow intersections](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11565/overlapping-red-and-green-arrayplots-to-show-yellow-intersections)
- [Color mixing or blend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14836/color-mixing-or-blend/14845#14845)

and the function `Blend[{ Image1 , Image2 }]`, but I didn't get a good result.

This is the closest example that I get using **Blend[{imag1,imag2}]**.

[image]

But this is not 100 % correct a time that if you combine two pure colors, pure red and green, I was expecting that the combination of these two pure colors result a image that had red, green and yellow colors, but not in the dark tone of these color.

Comment: Could you show the code you used to create the above images in Mathematica? Or are they imported from somewhere else? In other words are you wanting to treat external data (like fluorescence microscopy images) or are you wanting to do everything inside Mathematica (also the creation of the images)?

Comment: This images are from a external data. I would like to treat this images using Mathematica.

Comment: `ImageCompose[img, {img2, 0.5}]` is, I think, the way to go but it doesn't necessarily result in a "nice" scale of yellow colors.

Comment: When you use this function **ImageCompose[img, {img2, 0.5}]** you obtain the same result of **Blend[img , img2]** this result is like a average of interpolation of the two images. The image that result from these two function **ImageCompose[img, {img2, 0.5}]** and **Blend[img,img2]** has a color tone /2 from the pure yellow

Comment: @G.Candiotto . Hard to say but it looks from a first glance that the intensities are identical. If you combine both "red" and "green" images and then use `ColorSeparate[]` you end up with only the blue channel having less than a full intensity (except where the black lines are). Do you know where you are expecting the images not to match up, or have an example of what the output should be like?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the images are aligned and the same size, you can apply `Max` (or any other function) to each pixel color component like this:

```
imgs = Import /@ {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFlhC.png", 
    "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez2ql.png"};

Image[MapThread[Max, ImageData /@ imgs, 3]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hello nikie, first thanks for your attention. Your example is pretty good, but is necessary appears de colors red and green in the resultant image, a time that intersection region isn't 100% equal in the two images. The result that you plot in your example has the same result of function **ImageAdd[ img1 , Img2 ]**.

Comment: @G.Candiotto: You can use any function instead of `Max`. But you'll have to come up with a function yourself - I have no idea what kind of mapping you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a result that *might* be useful to you.  I cannot think of a simple way to restore the white background but perhaps I will come back to it later.

```
imgs = Import /@ {"https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFlhC.png", 
                  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez2ql.png"};

ImageApply[1 - {#[[2]], #2[[1]], #[[1]]} &, imgs]
```

[image]